# SAS Transpose and summarize

Tags: sql, sas, transpose, summary, enterprise-guide

I'm working on following scenario in SAS.

Input 1

```
AccountNumber   Loans
123             abc, def, ghi
456             jkl, mnopqr, stuv
789             w, xyz
```

Output 1

```
AccountNumbers  Loans
123             abc
123             def
123             ghi
456             jkl
456             mnopqr
456             stuv
789             w
789             xyz
```

Input 2

```
AccountNumbers  Loans
123             15-abc
123             15-def
123             15-ghi
456             99-jkl
456             99-mnopqr
456             99-stuv
789             77-w
789             77-xyz
```

Output 2

```
AccountNumber   Loans
123             15-abc, 15-def, 15-ghi
456             99-jkl, 99-mnopqr, 99-stuv
789             77-w, 77-xyz
```

I manged to get Input 2 from output 1, just need Output 2 now.

I will really appreciate the help.

Thanks!

Comment: How about showing some code that you've tried?

Comment: @sasfrog I used below code to get output 1 from input 1 and use my lookup values to input 2 now want to get data in its original state


`DATA TEMP
(KEEP = ACCOUNTNUMBER LOANS OUT)
;
SET XYZ;
CNT = COUNTW(LOANS,',');
     DO I = 1 TO CNT;
  OUT = STRIP(SCAN(LOANS,I,","));
     OUTPUT;
     END;
OUT = STRIP(OUT);


RUN;`

Comment: Your just reposting the answer to your previous question. What have you tried for this question? Also, edit your question, don't post code in the comments, it's illegible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, replacing [Input 2] with the actual name of your Input 2 table.

```
data output2 (drop=loans);
    do until (last.accountnumbers);
        set [Input 2];
        by accountnumbers;
        length loans_combined $100;
        loans_combined=catx(', ',loans_combined,loans);
    end;
run;
```